# How to add mathematical function as argument in python function

Tags: python, function, cryptanalysis

I know there are similar questions about passing functions into functions, but I'm not clear on the effective solution for my particular problem.

The following function works but the formula is static. It only works on a fixed function, namely (in mathy pseudocode) `f(a) = 3^a mod 17 = b` where  `f(11) = 7`

```py
def get_a(b):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    a = 1
    while(1):
            x = pow(3, a) % 17
            if x == b:
                return a
            if a > 10000:
                return -1
            a += 1


def main():
    b = 7
    a = get_a(7)
    print(F'The preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to make a user pass in any given function. To start with, I implemented something just a little more complex but still pretty simple.

```py
def get_a_variable(b, base, mod):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    a = 1
    while(1):
        # print(F'a:{a}, b{b}')
        x = pow(base, a) % mod
        # print(F'x:{x}')
        if x == b:
            return a
        if a > 10000:
            return -1
        a += 1

def main():
    b = 7
    a = get_a(7)
    print(F'The preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
    a = get_a_variable(7,3,17)
    print(F'Again, the preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
```

This works but I want to make it even more dynamic.

To try implement this, I created a new function that can be passed as an argument:

```py
def power_mod_function(base, x, mod):
  return power(base, x) % mod
```

I'm not exactly sure how the trial value arg x should be handled or if it should even be in this function.

Then I "forked" the "get_a(b)" function that takes a callback I believe

```py
def get_a_dynamic(b, crypt_func):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    a = 1
    while(1):
            x = crypt_func() # Not sure how to manage the arg passing here
            if x == b:
                return a
            if a > 10000:
                return -1
            a += 1
```

Then I updated main():

```py
def main():
    b = 7
    a = get_a(7)
    print(F'The preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
    a = get_a_dynamic(b, power_mod_function(3, x, 17)) # Not sure how to pass my middle arg!! 
    print(F'Again the preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
```

I'm getting the following error messages:

```
 python pre_img_finder.py
The preimage a of b=7 is: 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pre_img_finder.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "pre_img_finder.py", line 41, in main
    a = get_a_dynamic(b, power_mod_function(3, x, 17))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I don't know how to set it up right and do the variable passing so that I can pass the static variables once in main and the middle test variable x will always increment and eventually find the results I want.

Perhaps I just need to receive a function that begins with a "type" argument that acts as a kind of switch, and then takes a variable number of arguments depending on the type. For example, we could call the above a base-power-mod function or  (bpm), where "power" is the answer we're looking for, i.e. a is the pre-image of b in technical terms. Then just call

```py
main():
    a = get_a_dynamic(7, ("bpm", 3,17))
```

And then implement it that way?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*args` to pass additional arbitrary number of arguments to the function.

```
def get_a_dynamic(b, crypt_func, *args):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    a = 1
    while(1):
            x = crypt_func(*args) 
            if x == b:
                return a
            if a > 10000:
                return -1
            a += 1
```

Then call it in your main like this

```
def main():
    b = 7
    a = get_a(7)
    print(F'The preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
    a = get_a_dynamic(b, power_mod_function, 3, x, 17) 
    print(F'Again the preimage a of b={b} is: {a}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to generate dynamic functions with partial defined arguments is... `functools.partial`

```py
from functools import partial

def get_a_variable_with_func(b, func):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    a = 1
    while(1):
        x = func(a)
        if x == b:
            return a
        if a > 10000:
            return -1
        a += 1

b = 7

def power_mod_function(base, mod, x):
    return (base ** x) % mod

partial_func = partial(power_mod_function, 3, 17)

a = get_a_variable_with_func(7, partial_func)
print(a)
>>>
11
```

By the way, this is more pythonic:

```py
from functools import partial

def get_a_variable_with_func(b, func):
    '''
    Get preimage a from A for f(a) = b where b in B
    '''
    for a in range(10001):
        if func(a) == b:
            return a
    return -1

def power_mod_function(base, mod, x):
    return (base ** x) % mod

a = get_a_variable_with_func(7, partial(power_mod_function, 3, 17))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this :

```
a = get_a_dynamic(b, power_mod_function(3, x, 17))
```

you don't pass `power_mod_function` to `get_a_dynamic`, you pass its result
instead. To pass the function you just have to pass the function name.

Therefore, because the function needs a value internal to `get_a_dynamic` (the x arg) and also two external arguments (3 and 17), you must pass these two arguments to get_a_dynamic separately for it to be able to call the passed function with the three needed arguments.

For that purpose, the suggestion of AnkurSaxena could be used especially if if the number of args can vary. But you can also declare it like this :

```
def get_a_dynamic(b, crypt_func, pow, mod):
```

then use it like this :

```
a = get_a_dynamic(b, power_mod_function, 3, 17))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like:

```py
def get_a_dynamic(b, function, argtuple):
    # …
    x = function(*argtuple) # star-operator unpacks a sequence
    # … et cetera
```

… in essence. You can then always check the range of `argtuple` when passing it around, or be scrupulous about your calling conventions – but that star-operator unpack bit is the crux of what you are looking for, I think.

If you want to pass the name of the function as a string (as per your example) you can do something like:

```py
function = globals()["bpm"] # insert your passed string argument therein
```

… but that’s kind of sketchy and I don’t recommend it – better in that case to pre-populate a dictionary mapping function string names to the functions themselves.

Comment: Also: if you’re going to be calling a scalar numeric pure-function in a loop like that, you may enjoy Cython: https://cython.org/